# How to use vanilla javascript inside Reactjs component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using chartist.js and I am using the chartist within reactjs component.
I am referring this http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#simple-pie-chart

chartist.js:

```
var Chartist = {
    version:'0.9.5' 
}

(function (window, document, Chartist) {

var options = {
  labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
    return value[0]
  }
};

var responsiveOptions = [
  ['screen and (min-width: 640px)', {
    chartPadding: 30,
    labelOffset: 100,
    labelDirection: 'explode',
    labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
      return value;
    }
  }],
  ['screen and (min-width: 1024px)', {
    labelOffset: 80,
    chartPadding: 20
  }]
];

})();
```

Reactjs component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var data = {
  labels: ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Grapes'],
  series: [20, 15, 40]
};

showPieChart(data){
     new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', data, options, responsiveOptions);
}

class Chart extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <div className="center">
              {showPieChart}
          </div>
      </div>

    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

Nothing is displayed on web page. How can I access vanilla javascript inside react component.

Comment: Consider calling the function with data instead of passing a reference to the function

Comment: @baao How can I access functions/methods from .js file into my react component.

Comment: good explanations here -> https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html  with basic examples.

Comment: @stonerock I have the same issue you had, the wrapper missing features and decided to go with vanilla integration inside ReactJs. Can you help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64160680/how-to-integrate-plain-vanilla-javascript-inside-reactjs/64160798?noredirect=1#comment113458284_64160798

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little bit misleading, and can be interpreted in two ways.

**#1. If you're asking how to integrate Chartist library with React**, here's how you can do it:

There's a wrapper library, that already did it for us: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartist

You can use it as follow (example taken from their repo):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';

class Pie extends React.Component {
  render() {

    var data = {
      labels: ['W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10'],
      series: [
        [1, 2, 4, 8, 6, -2, -1, -4, -6, -2]
      ]
    };

    var options = {
      high: 10,
      low: -10,
      axisX: {
        labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
          return index % 2 === 0 ? value : null;
        }
      }
    };

    var type = 'Bar'

    return (
      <div>
        <ChartistGraph data={data} options={options} type={type} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Pie />, document.body)
```

**#2. If you generally asking how to integrate other libraries into React**, then I recommend you to check the official React docs, because there's a really good tutorial about the topic - [Integrating with Other Libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)

So, if you don't want to use the wrapper library (react-chartist), then you can check its main component too. It's a great starting point (that follows React recommendations) to understand how to create your own wrapper: https://github.com/fraserxu/react-chartist/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Yes I know we can make use of react-chartist but it is just wrapper around chartist.js also react-chartist have many features missing.

Comment: I want to make use of chartist.js which is vanilla javascript inside my react component. Can I make .js file and how can I access those functions inside react component i.e .jsx file.

Comment: So, if you don't want to use the library (the wrapper library), you can check its main component. It's a great starting point (that follows React recommendations) to understand how to create your own wrapper: https://github.com/fraserxu/react-chartist/blob/master/index.js